# How to create AWS IAM role attaching managed policy only using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, roles, policy

I am trying to use Boto3 to create a new instance role that will attach a managed policy only.

I have the following:

**Policy Name:** `my_instance_policy`

**Policy ARN:** `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/my_test_policy`

I want to create the role called 'my_instance_role' attaching attaching the above policy only.

Boto3 client has the `create_role()` function like below:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam')
response = client.create_role(
    Path='string',
    RoleName='string',
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument='string',
    Description='string'
)
```

Here, I do not see an option to use the policy ARN or name. My understanding is that `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` variable needs the JSON formatted policy document converted in to text.

Is it possible the way I am looking for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would have to create the role (as you are doing above) and then separately attach the managed policy to the role like this:

```
response = client.attach_role_policy(
    RoleName='MyRole', PolicyArn='<arn of managed policy>')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My understanding is `AssumeRolePolicyDocument='string'` will add an inline policy which I do not want. I just want the role with one or more managed policies. We can create this way on the IAM console. Is it possible to create this way using Boto3?

Comment: The ``AssumeRolePolicyDocument`` is for establishing the trust relationship for the newly created role (i.e. who can assume this role).  It has nothing to do with the permissions granted by the role.  To attach a managed policy to a role, use the ``attach_role_policy`` as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually figured it out and it is working now. In this case `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` is `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}`. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar question in regard to how to supplying the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` when creating an IAM role with boto3.

I used the following code...

```
assume_role_policy_document = json.dumps({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "greengrass.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
})

create_role_response = self._iam.create_role(
    RoleName = "my-role-name",
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument = assume_role_policy_document
)
```

Note that the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` is about defining the trust relationship and not the actual permissions of the role you are creating.